# How to access custom PATH programs from .desktop file

Tags: path, .desktop

I have a scripts directory that I have added to path (specifically in the ~/.bashrc).
I can run the scripts as expected from the terminal, but it says that the command is not found when I run it from the .desktop file. How can I get it to run the scripts in my folder just by the name like I can from the terminal.

### Edit

Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Run a script from the `.desktop` file. In the script  set up the environment and call the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either do what waltinator says or use the env command directly in the desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=script name
Type=Application
Exec=env PATH=/custom/path:"$PATH" script.sh
```